# Adding Attribute to HTML element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Utilizing jQuery .children...

```
var strHtml = $(dt.row(row_idx).child()).children().children().html();
```

...to pass in the following HTML:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Notes:</td>
    <td>some info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assistance Required:</td>
    <td>​Translation, writing and speaking capabilities </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unit:</td>
    <td>not listed</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I grab the label cells (`<td>Notes:</td>`, `<td>Assistance Required:</td>`, `<td>Unit:</td>`) and move to their next corresponding value cell to add a colspan property to the `<td>` and then return the finished html?

The result should look like...

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Notes:</td>
    <td colspan="12">some info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assistance Required:</td>
    <td colspan="12">Translation, writing and speaking capabilities </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unit:</td>
    <td colspan="12">not listed</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I assume you don't have access to the code that is generating the html?

Comment: Correct, I do not have access to the code generating the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your string and load up a temporary element you create in memory only with that string.

You can use the **[`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** pseudo-class selector to just select the second child `<td>` element in each row and then use the JQuery **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method to add an attribute to those elements:

```js
var strHTML = `<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Notes:</td>
    <td>some info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assistance Required:</td>
    <td>​Translation, writing and speaking capabilities </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unit:</td>
    <td>not listed</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

// Create a temporary element in memory only
var temp = document.createElement("div");

// Load the string into the temp element
$(temp).html(strHTML);

// Now, you can search through the element

$("td:nth-child(2)", temp).attr("colspan", "12"); // Add the attribtue to the second td in each tr
console.log($(temp).html());  // Get the HTML contents of the <table>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am fairly new to this, so I did not know about `td:nth-child(2)`, but how do I run it against the HTML in my variable `strHtml` since I need to return the variable with adjusted HTML?

Comment: So even though this is incorrect, in my mind the pseudo code is something like `strHtml  = $(strHTML).$("td:nth-child(2)").attr("colspan", "12"); `